# Split an audio file to play down each channel of 5.1 using C#.Net

Tags: c#, audio, split

I have a Sweex 5.1 PCI card and ideally I'd like to play separate mono audio down each channel.

Is this possible at all even if not using C#.Net?

As an insight, it's basically for a Halloween Party. I'd like to extend the speakers into different rooms and play sound effects from the PC thus one speaker in one room playing one sound, and so forth.

I've tried searching on here but the solutions seem to be the opposite way round :-/

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question might show you a path foward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160009/how-to-play-sound-on-different-speakers